# How can I get involved in the ethereum community?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, blockchain, contract-design

I am looking to become involved in the crypto-currency ecosystem in a way that best uses my talents. My background is in finance and in the past I’ve worked for one of the largest technology-focused hedge funds in the world as well as one of the most successful investment banks. I also have a background in computer science and can code, though im not as talented as many of those already in the community. I don’t want to quit my current job yet, but I wanted to get involved in the ecosystem in a way that uses my skills.

What do you all recommend that I do?

One thing I’ve wanted to do is to join a DAO that does angel investing but I haven’t found any that exist yet. For now, I am just reading white papers and trying to learn by asking questions online, but I’d like to do more.

Answer (score 1):

Keep doing exactly what you're doing(reading and finding information), the tech industry is quite different to the finance world you're coming from and is a bit more 'cowboy-ish' in the sense a lot of the professional and corporate systems just aren't in place/needed. Read and learn as much as you can and either starting or joining in on a project would probably be the best way to learn 'on the job'.

Answer (score 0):

What immediately strikes me is networking in the startup community. I think a number of opportunities will arise, including helping startups getting funded, becoming a startup member, connecting with investors who need consultancy.

You could also directly contact Enterprise Ethereum Alliance, The Ethereum Foundation, and I would recommend Consensys, all with precisely the same question. Consensys, actually, sounds like what you want as a direct employer.

Another angle that could work in parallel is to  develop your own concept you mentioned in the other thread, of a smart contract or protocol that enables legal entities to offer assurances on cash flows, or real legal entities with an onchain part of their constitution, and take that further and see where it leads.

Finally, another opportunity might be through networking with European startups in for example Barcelona and Berlin, help with business development by bringing their ideas to the USA (I assume you are there)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have been recently getting more involved in the Ethereum and blockchain industry by going to local meetups and hackthons like ([EthDenver](https://ethdenver.com/)). Now starting to get more involve in contributing with coding or just networking with others and see if they would like to partner up for a possible startup. So far, this method is working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

https://ethereum.org/en/community/get-involved has a wide range of suggestions for people of many different backgrounds and skillsets, including [Developers](https://ethereum.org/en/community/get-involved/#developers), [Financial professionals & Accountants](https://ethereum.org/en/community/get-involved/#financial-professionals), Product Managers, Researchers & Academics.

Some of the opportunities for developers include:

- Learn about and try Ethereum at ethereum.org/developers/
- [Find a bounty on Gitcoin](https://gitcoin.co), work on a small or large technical issue, earn crypto!
- Attend an [ETHGlobal](http://ethglobal.co) hackathon near you!
- Check out [projects related to your area of expertise or programming language of choice](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/programming-languages)

It also [lists some DAOs](https://ethereum.org/en/community/get-involved/#decentralized-autonomous-organizations-daos) and [jobs](https://ethereum.org/en/community/get-involved/#ethereum-jobs).